# Intalling from requirements.txt fails

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install the requirements of an old project and I am hitting a few problems. One of which I can't figure out is this error:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): wsgiref==0.1.2 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7 (from -r requirements.txt (line 38))
Installing collected packages: distribute, dj-database-url, django-celery, django-debug-toolbar, django-heroku-memcacheify, django-pylibmc-sasl, facebook-sdk, gdata, gevent, google-api-python-client, greenlet, gunicorn, htmlentities, httplib2, kombu, nltk, psycopg2, pygeoip, pylibmc, pymongo, python-dateutil, python-gflags, pytz, shortuuid, simplejson, sleekxmpp
  Running setup.py install for distribute
    Before install bootstrap.
    Scanning installed packages
    Setuptools installation detected at /Users/pp/www/hintortwoDEV/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-3.5.1-py2.7.egg
    Egg installation
    Patching...
    Renaming /Users/pp/www/hintortwoDEV/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-3.5.1-py2.7.egg into /Users/pp/www/hintortwoDEV/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-3.5.1-py2.7.egg.OLD.1401611004.21
    Patched done.
    Relaunching...
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    NameError: name 'install' is not defined
    Complete output from command /Users/pp/www/hintortwoDEV/venv/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/Users/pp/www/hintortwoDEV/venv/build/distribute/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-1G5NO8-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/pp/www/hintortwoDEV/venv/include/site/python2.7:
    Before install bootstrap.

Scanning installed packages

Setuptools installation detected at /Users/pp/www/hintortwoDEV/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-3.5.1-py2.7.egg

Egg installation

Patching...

Renaming /Users/pp/www/hintortwoDEV/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-3.5.1-py2.7.egg into /Users/pp/www/hintortwoDEV/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-3.5.1-py2.7.egg.OLD.1401611004.21

Patched done.

Relaunching...

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

NameError: name 'install' is not defined

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /Users/pp/www/hintortwoDEV/venv/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/Users/pp/www/hintortwoDEV/venv/build/distribute/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-1G5NO8-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/pp/www/hintortwoDEV/venv/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /Users/pp/www/hintortwoDEV/venv/build/distribute
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/pp/.pip/pip.log
```

I don't understand the error at all so you can provide explanation and logical fix for it that would be awesoming.

UPDATE 1:
(answering the questions in the comments)
@burhan: python is 2.7. I lost log because I cleaned it up to show you that specific error, but then other errors and then i couldn't reproduce it :(
@SeMeKh: yes, it says: `pip 1.5.6 from /Users/pp/www/hintortwoDEV/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)`
@Padraic: `distribute==0.6.28`

Comment: Can you attach the output of the log file `/Users/pp/.pip/pip.log`, and also your Python version.

Comment: Have you tried updating `pip`?

Comment: what version of `distribute` is in the `requirements.txt`?